# I want to Search a specific word in the string and show 4 words before and 4 words after finding the word in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to Search a specific word in the string and show 4 words before and 4 words after finding the word

Example : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

Search Term : printer took

Result I want :  ... the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type ...

Please Help me.

[image: Example 2]

Comment: do you need a regular expression?

Comment: No, I want to show come words before a specifice word and after like above example.

Comment: Well, you can't do that without regular expression. Create a function that will use one to get string list from a string. Use this answer to get it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756644/regex-to-search-for-5-words-before-and-after-a-given-word Then feed it as items to recyclerview or listview adapter that will show it in recyclerview that you've put in layout your layout.

Comment: Can you help me in writing a regular expression that gives me searched word and before 10 words and after.

Comment: I got a solution thanks for your atention.
(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}Word(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}